# UIImageView inside Scrollview - out of center while zooming

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, scrollview, center

I am trying to place an UIImageView inside a Scrollview.
I made constraints to center the UIImageView inside the Scrollview. That works, but if I zoom in, the position shifts to the right. So e.g. I am not able to zoom into the Image and see the far right part of the image.

It looks like that:
[image]

Any ideas why this happens, and how I can solve the problem?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

Behaviour at the moment:
[image]

How it should behave:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning or constraining something directly inside a scroll view makes absolutely no sense at all (unless you know how to leverage derived height of childs to work for you correctly)

A UIScrollView is not a UIView per se. It providers a wrapper around child views that are scrollable within a fixed height(the height of the UIScrollView).

The content that will scroll will be the height of the contentView (direct child of the UIScrollView or the derived height of all items inside). Note I'm talking about vertical scroll view here. Horizontal has the same principles.

If you want to center the UIImageView inside the "content" of the UIScrollView, then define **one** child UIView under the UIScrollView and give it a height larger than the UIScrollView height. You can then try centering your UIImageView by setting constraints to the UIView.

```
-> UIScrollView
    -> ContentView (UIView) //constraint this and pin edges to UIScrollView
        -> UIImageView //constraint this with the ContentView, not UIScrollView
```

Comment: Hello jms,
thank you very much for that answer! As you can imagine I am very new to swift, and all tutorials I have found, didn't mention that. 
So I added an UIView between my UIScrollView and UIImageView, made the UIScrollView and UIView the same width and height, and centered the UIImageView inside the UIView. Now the Image is centered as expected, and I can zoom in and out! There is only one new problem. If I zoom and drag it the one side, I have some white area, because the contentView is larger then the Image, is there a possibility to send the bounds to the UIImageView while zooming?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You need to increase the width of the UIImageView to the width of the contentView upon zooming in??

Comment: Hello, I added two pictures in my first post, I hope this helps understand my problem. I don't want to have that white areas, while I am zooming, if I zoom into, and shift the image to one of the far most direction, I would like to have it stick to the border of the image, not to the border of the contentview.

Comment: There is no logical way to approach your problem using normal zooming scenarios. What you need is a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` while knowing that you CAN adjust Autolayout constraints during runtime (just drag the constraint onto storyboard). You will have to write some logic to reflect your scenario of pinching out (reducing top and left constraint to 0) and back in (reverting the previous). You may also consider removing the scrollview since I do not see it adding any value here (unless this is just a sample and you have more items there that actually span larger than the viewport)